# "504 Gateway Timeout" while executing python cgi script

Tags: python, nginx, astropy

The following example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from astropy.time import Time
from astropy.coordinates import solar_system_ephemeris, EarthLocation, get_body

print('Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8\n')

t = Time("2014-09-22 23:22")
loc = EarthLocation.of_site('greenwich') 
with solar_system_ephemeris.set('builtin'):
    jup = get_body('jupiter', t, loc) 
print('<h2>',jup.ra.deg,'</h2>')
```

works OK when the script runs locally (=136.9111620895066). But if I try to execute it from the server a "504 Gateway Time-out" Nginx error appears.

Maybe something is wrong with the file where astropy holds the ephemerides data? Other astropy, matplotlib, etc. scripts work fine from the server. The error appears every time the script needs ephemerides flles (jpl, esa ...).

Comment: Can you also post your Nginx configuration?

Comment: How are you calling this script (ex. client -- Nginx -- script)? The error means Nginx is waiting for a response to give back to the client (or whoever called this script), but your script does not provide a response (i.e. it just `print`s it to stdout).

Comment: isn't print('<h2>',jup.ra.deg,'</h2>') supposed to return to the client the result inside <h2> tags?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest bugfix release of astropy (v3.2.3, http://docs.astropy.org/en/latest/changelog.html#id153) since it fixes an issue with IERS URLs, which is likely the cause of you "504 Gateway Time-out" error.